# Как избавиться от конфликта имен Excel при открытии через Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

Дорогие программисты, у меня возникает такая проблема, которая не дает мне спать иногда, буквально.
Ежедневно нужно подготовить рапорт в формате Excel, я автоматизировал его подготовку с помощью скрипта в языке Powershell. Проблема происходит при открытии файла.

```
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible=$True
$xl.DisplayAlerts=$False
$fileName="c:\path\to\my\file.xlsx"
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.open("$fileName",3)
$sheetName="mainSheet"
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.item("$sheetName")
...
```

[image: Скриншот того, что остонавливает мой скрипт]

Я пытался уже убрать/комментировать строку Visible=$True и даже сохранил файл с другим именем. 
Большая проблема в том, что так не всегда бывает. Иногда выполняется хорошо, но если нет, придется рано проснуться октрыть удаленное соединение с компьютером и вручную вводить какое-нибудь новое имя, и дальше скрипт выполняется.

Есть ли у вас какие-нибудь предложения? Благодарю за ранее за внимание.

Comment: `$xl.Visible` - только визуальное отображение приложения (показать/скрыть), к именам отношения не имеет. Имя открываемой книги - `file.xlsx`, название листа - `mainSheet`. Ошибка с именем `Print_Area`. Проблема с диапазоном для печати? Вот его и ищите в книге. Возможно, в книге есть именованный диапазон, который ссылается на внешние источники. При открытии файла идет запрос на обновление данных, но Вы его не видите (сообщения отключены - `DisplayAlerts=$False`), при обновлении чего-то там происходит.... Но это догадка.

Comment: Если включаю отображение сообщений, то программа останавливается пока не нажимаю "ОК". Но такая проблема тоже бывает у другого файла но конфликт будет с именем "Database". Да я предполагаю, что это какой-то скрытный диапазон, ведь файл был много раз использован многими людьми. Я просто хотел, чтобы программа сама выбрала "программатически" либо новое имя и "ОК" либо "отмена". На старом компьютере Windows 7 и Office 2016 таких конфликтов не было, программа до конца выполнялась, только как обновлили на Windows 10 и Office 365 я обнаружил этот конфликт.

Comment: >> * программа останавливается пока не нажимаю "ОК"*  Если сообщение об обновлении связей - найдите в 'Powershell', как отключать обновления пр открытии книги

Comment: Отключать обновления не идеальный вариант, раз именно этот файл имеет много связей, которые нужно обновить. Когда включаю сообщения конфликта нет, но придется вручную закрыть окна.